# How can I clear an arc or circle in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found that there's a `clearRect()` method, but can't find any to clear an arc (or a full circle).

Is there any way to clear an arc in canvas?

Comment: Once you need to clear complex shapes, canvas abstraction library could come useful. That's exactly why [I built one](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/). Perhaps it could come useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, once you've drawn something on a canvas there is no object to clear, just the pixels you've drawn.  The `clearRect` method doesn't clear a previously drawn object, it just clears the pixels in the space defined by the parameters.  You can use the `clearRect` method to clear the arc if you know a rectangle which contains it.  This will of course clear any other pixels in the area, so you'll have to redraw them.

Edit: [MooGoo has given a much better answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3566385/8655)

Comment: This is good advice. If you're concerned about clearing other content around your arc, consider separating the objects you're drawing onto multiple canvases (stacked on top of one another).  That way a small clearRect around your arc doesn't end up erasing some of your background content, and you can still avoid taking the huge performance hit from context.clearRect(0,0,screenWidth, screenHeight).

Answer (score 48):

There is no `clearArc` however you can use Composite Operations to achieve the same thing

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
```

According to MDC the effect of this setting is

> The existing content is kept where it doesn't overlap the new shape.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing

So any filled shape with this mode on will end up erasing current canvas content.

Comment: Thanks! Each frame of my animation dropped from 7ms to 0.5ms using this method.

Answer (score 17):

This is a circular equivalent of `clearRect()`.  The main thing is setting up a composite operation per @moogoo's answer.

```
var cutCircle = function(context, x, y, radius){
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.fill();
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html:

Answer (score 10):

You can use the clearRect() method to erase a portion of the canvas (including your arc), but when you're using clearRect() with arcs or anything else that you used beginPath() and closePath() for while drawing, you'll need to handle the paths while erasing, too.  Otherwise, you may end up with a faded version of your arc still appearing.

```
//draw an arc (in this case, a circle)
context.moveTo(x, y);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
context.closePath();
context.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
context.stroke();

//now, erase the arc by clearing a rectangle that's slightly larger than the arc
context.beginPath();
context.clearRect(x - radius - 1, y - radius - 1, radius * 2 + 2, radius * 2 + 2);
context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to call beginPath()

```
function animate (){
 requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 

  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x,y,40,0,Math.PI * 2,false); 
  c.strokeStyle='rgba(200,0,0,1)';
  c.stroke();

 c.fillStyle ='rgba(0,0,0,1)';
 c.fillRect(x,y,100,100);
 x++


} animate()
```

Credit to @Gabriele Petrioli in this answer: [Why doesn't context.clearRect() work inside requestAnimationFrame loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440413/why-doesnt-context-clearrect-work-inside-requestanimationframe-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated fiddle for you too (uses clearRect): https://jsfiddle.net/x9ztn3vs/2/

It has a clearApple function:

```
block.prototype.clearApple = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(this.x - 6, this.y - 6, 2 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
}
```