# How do you redraw a canvas circle without residue?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, asp.net-mvc-5, drawing

I am working on a MVC 5 application that draws 120 sections of a circle that represents data.

On the initial drawing, the circle looks smooth:

[image: Smooth Circle]

However, after redrawing the circle to present updated data (using javascript), the circle doesn't look as smooth. There is "residue" from redrawing the circle.

[image: Rough Circle]

Therefore, **How do you redraw a canvas circle without residue?**

---

**.cshtml**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
{
    var myCanvas = "myCanvas" + i;
    <canvas id=@myCanvas width="355" height="355"></canvas>
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var start = 1.5; // top of circle
var end = start + 0.01667;

for (var j = 0; j < 120; j++) {
var myCanvas = "myCanvas" + j;
var canvas = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 152;
var startAngle = start * Math.PI;
var endAngle = end * Math.PI;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
context.lineWidth = 9;

// line color
if (/*there is data*/) {
    context.strokeStyle = /*data color*/;
} else {
    context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
}

context.stroke();

if (end >= 1.99) { // reset to draw the rest of the circle
    start = 0;
    end = 0 + 0.01667;
} else {
    start += 0.01667;
    end += 0.01667;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a [clearRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) call between draws?

Comment: @zero298 Negative. I also tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22145461) to no avail.

Comment: You will need to redraw the whole thing or split it up and draw parts on different canvas and combine them when you need to display. You can think of it as layers. You can create a canvas in code and dont need to add it to the DOM. Just draw the layer canvas onto the display canvas. ie `ctx.drawImage(offScreenCanvas,0,0)`

Comment: Refactor your code to use a single canvas containing all your multiple circle-sections. And do `clearRect` before redrawing your circle.

Comment: @markE do you have an example of how to do that? i think i would have preferred to do this if i knew how.

Comment: @zero298 I stand corrected. clearRect() wasn't working for me was because I was [running it once instead of running it for each section of the circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092308/how-do-you-redraw-a-canvas-circle-without-residue/35096864#comment57984003_35096864). Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the canvas elements need to be cleared before drawing the next color.

```js
var clearCanvas = false;

function drawChunks() {
  var start = 1.5; // top of circle
  var end = start + 0.01667;

  function rColor() {
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
    c = "#" + "000000".substr(c.length) + c;
    return c;
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < 120; j++) {

    var myCanvas = "myCanvas" + j;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (clearCanvas == true) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 152;
    var startAngle = start * Math.PI;
    var endAngle = end * Math.PI;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    context.lineWidth = 9;

    // line color
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1) {
      context.strokeStyle = rColor();
    } else {
      context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
    }

    context.stroke();

    if (end >= 1.99) { // reset to draw the rest of the circle
      start = 0;
      end = 0 + 0.01667;
    } else {
      start += 0.01667;
      end += 0.01667;
    }
  }
}


var rad = document.myForm.clear_canvas;
var prev = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
  rad[i].onclick = function() {
    clearCanvas = this.value == 'yes' ? true : false;
  };
}


drawChunks();
setInterval(drawChunks, 1000);
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  Clear Canvas? yes
  <input name="clear_canvas" type="radio" value="yes">| no
  <input name="clear_canvas" type="radio" value="no" checked>
</form>
<hr/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
      var myCanvas = "myCanvas" + i;
      var canvas = '<canvas id=@myCanvas width="355" height="355"></canvas>';
      html += canvas.replace(/\@myCanvas/, myCanvas);
    }
    document.write(html);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to do `canvas.replace(/\@myCanvas/, myCanvas);` the `@myCanvas` already reads the value of the variable. Note that this code using the razor view syntax for an MVC 5 application.

Comment: Really nice example. The reason clearRect() wasn't working for me was because I was only running the function once (where `j = 0`) instead of clearing the canvas each time.