# Why doesn't context.clearRect() work inside requestAnimationFrame loop?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas element on the page that is having a circle drawn and moved on it. The circle is being moved by one pixel in every iteration of the loop. Here is the code.

```js
  function clearPage() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,300, 150);
  };

  var canvasEl = document.getElementById("main");
  var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
  
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
 
  var x = 0;
  function moveCircle() {
    clearPage();
    context.arc(x, 75, 20, 0, 2* Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
    x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle);
  }
  moveCircle();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id='main'></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As is evident, my function clears the page before drawing the new circle. Though when run, you can see that it leaves the previously drawn circles on the page. If you were to call the clearPage() function after it finished animating, the whole page would get cleared like expected.

More than anything, I just want to know why this is happening. It doesn't seem to be completely intuitive but my best guess is that it has to do with the behavior of requestAnimationFrame();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `context.beginPath();` before drawing the arc.

The reason is that the arcs are added to to the same path so each command redraws the whole path (see https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-arc). Using the `beginPath` starts a new path for each arc and thus does not redraw the previous ones.

```js
function clearPage() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,300, 150);
  };

  var canvasEl = document.getElementById("main");
  var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
  
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
 
  var x = 0;
  function moveCircle() {
    clearPage();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, 75, 20, 0, 2* Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
    x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle);
  }
  moveCircle();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id='main'></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, it works. I've looked up the beginPath() method but I'm still not 100% sure why clearing the page wouldn't work in this case. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: @JustinHathaway added some explanation.

Comment: @JustinHathaway 2D context stores draw operations, `arc`, `rect`, `moveTo`, `lineTo`, .. etc as one path and does not render them until you issue a `fill` or `stroke`. `beginPath` tells the context to release all the path information and start a new one. When you do not use `beginPath()` you are effectively adding to the existing path, every time you call `stroke` or `fill` you draw the current path being all the arcs you added

Comment: Gaby and @Blindman67: Thank you both for your answers and clear explanations. Helped a ton!